# Real-Time Excel Updates

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have a third party application that updates cell values by opening the excel file, setting values in cells, and writing (saving) the excel file. Suppose I have the excel spreadsheet open at all times, how I do have the spreadsheet reflect these changes in real-time?

Every time there is an update, I have to re-open the excel file to see the new changes.

PS. I am using the Apache POI.

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with "Every time there is an update, I have to re-open the excel file to see the new changes."? If you want to know which cells have been changed, you'll have to do the diff yourself ...

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, because of the nature of excel file, i have observed it saying "sharing voilation", you can though write a bat file which will open excel file and have this bat file executed by a program, everytime the file is updated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this using Apache POI.  If you have an Excel spreadsheet open in Excel, then you will get a `FileNotFoundException` if you attempt to write your changes to that file.  At least on Windows, you will get something like this:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: MySpreadsheet.xlsx (The process cannot access the
file because it is being used by another process)
```

Additionally, even if this worked, there is nothing in the Apache POI API that interacts with the Excel application itself, so you cannot tell Excel to re-open the spreadsheet.

Comment: Why should Excel re-open the spreadsheet? It's written by the 3rd party app and read by POI. A simple polling on the file modification timestamp and some error handling in case the file is just written should be sufficient ... I don't see a real problem here ...